# Eclipse PDT/PHP : Remove folder from validation

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, buildpath

I use Eclipse with PDT, Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

I have a folder called "var" in my PHP project that I would like to exclude from build, so I excluded it in Build Path using `var/**`. Though, even then, it still give me errors in this folder after doing a clean/build. I also tried `var/`, `var/*` and all combinations of those. Nothing do it, Eclipse still validate those files. Those are temporary files, so it's really annoying to have the IDE working for nothing on those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buld Path is for PHP validator excludes. You have couple options:

1. Exclude from workspace. Right click on level up dir (project) -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters.
2. Create excludes inside project -> validation page.
3. Mark dir as library. When is part of build path, right click on it -> Use as library folder.